# PublishNext element from the flux only if the first emitted event doesn't met criteria

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

UserPreferenceFlux holds the information of User preferences in priority order and we have to consider second preference only nothing matches with first preference. Preference match requires a blocking I/O call. I tried with below code, even though there is a match with User first preference, I can see that a WebClient call is made for the second preference which is unnecessary (as first match preference is already in progress).

```
Flux<UserPreference> userPreferenceFlux = getUserPreferences();
UserPreferenceFlux 
.flatMap(preference -> checkForMatch()) // Blocking IO call for match check
.filter(preference -> preference.isMatchFound())
.next(); // The Idea is to consider next preference if current preference is 
         // not found
```

Comment: What does `checkForMatch()` do? Can you show the code? Does it return a boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concatMap` instead of `flatMap`.

By default flatMap will request 256 preferences from the source and process them all at once. This "all-at-once" behavior is diminished by the fact that your `checkForMatch()` seems to be blocking, but still: the source itself is requested more than what you want.

`concatMap` on the other hand will request preferences from the source one by one, waiting until the current `UserPreference` has been processed before requesting the next one.

Comment: Thanks @Simon thats what I am looking for.